# Логирование в log4j, вывод в лог info и warn возможно?

Tags: java, log4j

Добрый день!

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в логи писались и warn'ы и info ? Или можно только что-то одно?

Сейчас в настройках log4j.properties следующее:

log4j.rootLogger=info, file

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Уровни логирование в Log4j выглядят так:

- TRACE
- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- FATAL

Выставляя в конфиге уровень INFO вы позволяете логировать сообщения для уровней INFO  и ниже (т.е. WARN, ERROR и FATAL).

Отвечая конкретно на ваш вопрос, можно сказать, что установив уровень логирования в INFO, вы получите в своем логе и сообщения уровня WARN.

Comment: Большущее спасибо!

Comment: @drcosmo Если вас устраивает ответ, то просто примите его нажав соотвествтующую кнопку.